# Is it possible to virtualize a Genband/Broadsoft M6 voip telephony system?

Tags: backup, virtualization, vmware-esx, voip

I work with a company that runs a hosted VOIP platform originally known as the Genband M6 acquired by Broadsoft a few years back.  This system is going end of life March 2016 and will no longer be receiving vendor support of any kind at that point.

As such, we're looking at ways to ensure we can continue using the platform as is as long as we need to.  It's a mature and stable platform at this point but there's concerns relative to hardware failure and what not.

I am not familiar with this hardware unfortunately so I'm hoping I can get some advice from an expert in the field if this is even a path worth considering.

Does anyone have experience with virtualizing this platform?

Comment: What does the platform run on?

Comment: Have you confirmed with your legal department this is even something you'd want to do as an organization?

Comment: Does it even have vendor support now? I can't even find a web page about it, documentation, or anything.

Comment: @theterribletrivium I'm just concerned with the technical feasibility of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton We pay for some very limited extended support currently, but starting in March 2016 we've been told there will be absolutely no one that will take support calls for it.

Comment: Hm. I don't see the problem as virtualizing it, then, but what to replace it with and how quickly you can do so. Running a system that's not only out of support but also not very well known is quite a high risk proposition.

Comment: @ewwhite I think it's an ancient linux or bsd, but I'm not positive.  Unfortunately this is a very small company and the last really knowledgeable engineer left about a year ago so we lack solid domain knowledge, hence the reliance on vendor support.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh, I agree completely and we're exploring other migration options.  Unfortunately the intended upgrade for this product is for bigger players and would price us out of the market.  So we're looking into resellers of the new platform and I'm pushing to see if an Asterisk solution could be a cost saving option.  But in the meantime, I want to figure out a way to at least give us the option to use it as long as we can.